# Problems with 403 forbidden on URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to 403-block an URL (`/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=force_refresh_get_site_version`) using mod_rewrite. This is the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \baction=force_refresh_get_site_version\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

... however this gives me a 404.

But if I remove these two lines:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

... I get a 403 forbidden. Somewhat confusing. Thanks for any help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

> Somewhat confusing.

Yes, it makes no sense! There would seem to be "something else" going on?

The directive you posted would block the stated URL - in fact it would possibly block too much, as you are not checking the URL-path. To block that *specific* URL you would use something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=force_refresh_get_site_version$
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin-ajax.php$ - [F]
```

The `L` flag is superfluous, it is *implied* when you use the `F` flag.

One possible reason for the 404 response status is if your custom 403 (defined in either `.htaccess` or your server config) overrides the status code and explicitly sets a 404. (This is not that uncommon on some shared servers.) However, this does not seem to tie-up with the what you are seeing below...

> But if I remove these two lines:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> ```

Those two lines are seemingly unrelated to the problem, as the preceding directive should have already blocked the request.

The first `RewriteRule` is simply an "optimisation" that prevents an unnecessary filesystem check when the front-controller is invoked (by the last `RewriteRule` directive).

If you remove the first `RewriteCond` directive then it would mean that this request (the request you are trying to block) would otherwise get processed by the WordPress front-controller (was it not for the earlier directives that should be blocking the request). This is more likely to result in a 404, not a 403. It will also break all links to status resources (CSS, JS, images, etc.) so your site is unlikely to work properly?!

Check for any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path as these could have created a conflict?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the suggested RewriteCond and RewriteRule you suggested to block the URL. However, I'm still getting a 404.

This is on a shared sever so there might be something fishy going on?

There are no other .htaccess-files in the path that could cause a conflict.

When I'm getting the 404 the static resources (CSS, JS etc.) still loads properly.

Anyway, I got sick of this problem and solved it by some code changes in the PHP-files instead.

Thanks for the reply, again!